# MFC PropertyGrid will not expand on user click (disabled)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm actually working with the MFC Property grid and, I wish to allow the user to expand the Items.

Basically I'm adding items to a MFC Property grid

```
CMFCPropertyGridProperty* mParent = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("cycle"));
mGrid.AddProperty(mParent);
mParent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Id"),        _T("test")));
mParent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Name"),      _T("test")));
mParent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("DateStart"), _T("test")));
mParent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("DateStop"),  _T("test")));
```

Basically I want all Items to be nonExpanded when I add them but I want the user to be able to expand them However, it seems that the default behavior is to prevent the user from expanding Items...

So far I've tried `Enable(true)` and `EnableActiveAccessibility()` but those doesn't seem to work...

Any idea which property I should set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very obvious, but you need to call [CMFCPropertyGridProperty::Expand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb983256%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with the `bExpand` parameter as FALSE!

> Parameters [in] bExpand TRUE to expand the property; FALSE to collapse the property. The default value is TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I might have not been clear enough... What I want is for the user to be able to expand and the property works only in the code.

Comment: Example : http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/1928/06h1.png          (That's two different images).